# href with a plist link not resolving in python app

Tags: python, django, plist

I have some legacy code that we are moving over to our Django project and am wondering why this href does not resolve as anticipated. It should open an enterprise version of our mobile app. When clicked it is interpreted as a url by Django and therefore we get a 403 page not found. I'm assuming Django hates the formatting of the url but, What gives?

```
<a href="itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=https://dl.dropbox.com/s/lwnsbatj8snq07o/myapp.plist"><button type='button' class='btn-default'>Download</button></a>
```

Comment: Are you sure your Django server is involved at all? I'm not very familiar with itms-services scheme, but this URL looks like something that's interpreted entirely by the mobile browser which then fetches from dropbox (and that URL returns a 403 for me).

Comment: We have the project running on a test server and the response returns with our vm's ip address attached like so, 127.0.0.0/'plist link from above', changed the error code to 403 that was a mistype

Comment: I meant that the dropbox URL returns a 403.

Comment: Django doesn't - and can't - change the way your browser interprets links: it just serves HTML to the browser. You should show how that HTML is generated.

Answer (score 0):

This can't possibly have anything to do with Django. Django doesn't - and can't - change the way your browser interprets links: it just serves HTML to the browser.